# Datastudio: Blended Data: Datetime can't be aggregated

Tags: looker-studio

I have two tables `case` and `party`. Both of them are from BigQuery. In the `case` table, there is a date field in the `DATETIME` type in BigQuery. I want to plot a chart to show the number of cases per month. It works perfectly when I only use the `case` table.

[image: case number per month]
[image: date shows in Year Month type]

However, when I blend the `case` table with the `party` table, the aggregation doesn't apply on the date field anymore.

[image: multiple rows with the same year month doesn't aggregate into one row]

This is how I join the tables.

[image: join by case id]
[image: apply inner join]

How do make the aggregation of date & time fields in blends work as normal?

#### Update

I have tried to create a custom field with `TODATE(date, 'RFC_3339', '%Y-%m-%d')`, but the aggregation is still not applied to the custom field.

### minimal example

1. Create `a.csv` in local.

```
a_id,date
1,2022-05-25T00:00:00
2,2022-05-25T00:00:00
3,2022-06-01T00:00:00
4,2022-06-02T00:00:00
```

2. Create `b.csv` in local.

```
a_id,b_id
1,1
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
4,6
```

3. Upload `a.csv` and `b.csv` into a Data Studio report.
4. Blend `a.csv` and `b.csv` with inner joining on `a_id` field. I removed "Record Count" from metrics in both tables and added all fields as dimensions.
5. Add a "Table" type chart using the blend created in the previous step.
6. Put `date` field as the only one dimension and select "Year Month" as the type.
7. Put `a_id` field as the only one metrics and select "Count Distinct" as aggregation.

#### actual result

| date (Year Month) | a_id |
| --- | --- |
| May 2022 | 2 |
| Jun 2022 | 1 |
| Jun 2022 | 1 |

#### expected result

| date (Year Month) | a_id |
| --- | --- |
| May 2022 | 2 |
| Jun 2022 | 2 |

#### example report

[Here](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/c7c65fa1-6bdc-4c52-8d38-391ab46a96b8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug, and it was already reported in [Google's DataStudio IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:196095).

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179280180

You probably want to star the issue (Google prioritize issues by the number of affected users).

Also, in the same thread, the reporting user suggests to use the above formula as a workaround.

```
YearMonthAsDate = DATE(YEAR(date_tran),MONTH(date_tran),1)
```

It worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the Date dimension in the table but in order to aggregate it on a monthly basis but joins the rows on a date base.

The solution is to change the Dimension to Month year inside the blend settings, you can do this just the same way you change a field type inside a table.